# Removing .html and index.html from URL

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm having some problems trying to

1. Remove the .html extension from URLs
2. Removing 'index.html' from an URL

1) To remove the extension I have tried using this in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

However when I click links in my HTML such as `<a href="abcde.html"></a>` it doesn't remove the .html from the URL and I am left with `www.website.com/abcde.html`

2) I tried using this to remove the index.html

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I load an index.html file on my server, my URL looks something like this

```
www.website.com/folder//
```

I am left with an extra `/` at the end.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer Anagio provided, let's cover all your requirements:

- Transparently serve .html files on requests like `/path/to/file` if `/path/to/file.html` exists
- Deny direct requests against `/path/to/file.html`
- Serve `/index.html` on requests against `/`

Directory configuration:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
#
# Rewrite valid requests on .html files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html?rw=1 [L,QSA]
#
# Return 404 on direct requests against .html files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rw=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182067/804087)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```